# rolling correlation not working with offset window

Tags: python, pandas

**Note**: I'm working with pandas 0.19 using the new `rolling` object rather than the deprecated `rolling_cor` function.

---

I have a dataframe indexed with irregular timestamps. I would like to calculate the rolling correlation between its columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A': np.random.randn(3600).cumsum(),
        'B': np.random.randn(3600).cumsum()
    }, index=pd.date_range('2016-01-01', freq='s', periods=3600)
)
```

The following returns the same result regardless of what the offset is:

```
offset = '1000s'  # or '100s' or '10s'...
df.rolling(offset).corr().loc[:, 'A', 'B'].plot();
```

In other words, the value of `offset` does not change the result of the calculation. I have the same problem using this approach:

```
df['A'].rolling(offset).corr(df['B']).plot();
```

Note that the examples below work as expected:

```
df['A'].rolling(1000).corr(df['B']).plot();  # window size, not offset
df.rolling(offset).sum().plot();  # sum, not corr
```

For now I will resample and use a fixed-size window, but I would like to know if this is a bug?

Comment: There are not equal here. perhaps a problem with plot? plot sometimes doesn't refresh between two calls.

Comment: Thanks, but I doubt it, I think I've tried enough times, and it always fails with an offset, and always works with a fixed-size window. What pandas version are you using? I'm on 0.19.1. Maybe it was fixed in 0.19.2?

Comment: Effectively : '0.19.2+0.g825876c.dirty' . I like the dirty.

Comment: @IanS did you find any solution?

Comment: @Stergios unfortunately no

Comment: @Ians Thanks! :(

Comment: I met the same problem ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55690261/pandas-rolling-correlation-behaves-weirdly-with-time-offset)) with version 0.21.1.
Did you find a solution?

Comment: @ItamarMushkin no I did not, I still resample before using a fixed-size window.

Comment: Did you try future versions? If so, I'll know it won't help (if not, I'll try it myself)

Comment: @ItamarMushkin no I didn't, sorry :) if you find out let me know!

Comment: Problem persists in 0.25 to the best of my knowledge