# pandas rolling correlation behaves weirdly with time offset

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I'm trying to calculate a rolling correlation between two columns of a `pandas` (0.21.1) dataframe, using a time offset as the rolling window.

Using an `int` window=n, I get the expected behavior - the first non-nan entry, which is the n-th row, is the correlation calculated using the first n rows; the following row is the correlation using the 1:n+1 rows, etc.

However, using a `pd.Timedelta` window, I get an entirely different result - the n-th row is the same, but the n+1-th row is the correlation calculated using the first n+1 rows - like the **value of the window doesn't matter**, even if I have a `DateTimeIndex`.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2019-01-01',freq='1min',periods=100),columns=['a','b'])
df['a']=range(100)
df['b']=[100+0.4*x + 17 * np.random.normal(0,1,1)[0] for x in range(100)]
```

'Manual' calculation of correlation based on rows 1 to 11:

```
print(((df-df.mean())/df.std()).iloc[1:11].corr())

a    1.000000
b    0.277464
Name: 2019-01-01 00:10:00, dtype: float64
```

Correlation using an `int` window:

```
print(df.rolling(10)['a'].corr(df.rolling(10)['b']).iloc[10])

          a         b
a  1.000000  0.277464
b  0.277464  1.000000
```

Correlation using an offset window (should be same as timedelta, both didn't work):

```
print(df.rolling('10min')['a'].corr(df.rolling('10min')['b']).iloc[10])
a    1.000000
b    0.175995
Name: 2019-01-01 00:10:00, dtype: float64
```

What am I not getting here?

Comment: I got what you are trying to say, but maybe it's best to show the whole dataframe rather than only a slice of it to illustrate your point. it looks like a bug in pandas to be honest .... Someone had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42623154/rolling-correlation-not-working-with-offset-window)

Comment: I thought that showing the whole df would just make the question even longer than it already is.
Anyway, that's indeed the same problem as in the link... but there's no solution there. Maybe it is a bug.

Comment: for pandas 0.23.4 the first 2 calculations ("maual", rolling int window) yield the same numbers

Comment: So it was for 0.21. That's not the question... the question is how to use the third, an offset window (to get the benefits of using an offset and not depend on index resolution)